# Weird behaviour with ui.router sref

Tags: angularjs

Feel like i'm going insane ..

```
{
    state: 'solicitation.details',
    config: {
        url: '/details/:stype',
        parent: 'solicitation',
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            return 'app/solicitation/templates/' + $stateParams.stype + '.html';
        },
        controller: 'DetailsController',
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        title: 'Solicitation Details'
    }
},
```

And it gets generated like this for stype=request:

```
<a ng-class="vm.disable.details ? 'disabled' : ''" class="btn btn-default" href="#/solicitation/self/details/request" role="button" ui-sref="solicitation.details({type: vm.type})">Details</a>
```

On click I get an error:

Warning: Error routing to Solicitation Details. Cannot GET /app/solicitation/templates/.html

If i input the route manually in to the browser (http://xxxx.com/#/solicitation/self/details/request) it works .. WTF

Added a console.log to templateUrl function:

```
templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
    var stype = $stateParams.stype;
    console.log(stype);
    return 'app/solicitation/templates/' + stype + '.html';
},
```

Output:

```
request //STYPE ACTUALLY GETS POPULATED
solicitation.route.js:58 
angular.js:9866 GET http://localhost:3000/app/solicitation/templates/.html 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:11655 Warning: Error routing to Solicitation Details. Cannot GET /app/solicitation/templates/.html
```

Comment: One problem spotted from your `ui-sref`: you have `{type: vm.type}` instead of `{stype: vm.type}` (as you have set `stype` in your state configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you shouldn't be using the href tag as ui-router only relies on ui-sref for routing.